# Can I obtain the exception or reason a message put into the dead letter / poison queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, dead-letter

I am using Azure's service bus with the web jobs SDK as described in [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/) with the dead letter (poison) queue. Keeping it simple, I'm using POCO queue messages. When a message processing function fails enough times, the message is moved to the dead letter queue.

I have another webjob consuming the dead letter queue to notify the team that something went wrong.

Is there any way to obtain the exception/reason that the message was moved into the dead letter queue? For instance, if the POCO message failed serialization and was hence moved to the dead letter queue, what's the best way to find that out?

I would like to try to avoid manually handling errors, putting messages into the dead letter queue myself, etc. The webjobs SDK does all that admirably.

Answer (score 0):

The WebJob re-tries to deliver the message configured number of times (default 10). If the delivery continues to fail (exception) the message is moved to dead-letter queue with the reason as MaxDeliveryCountExceeded. If you need further details, explicit dead-lettering need to be used.